# Multisite Network Admin

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I installed multisite on Wordpress. I don't have any problems with the panels of either site. But I cannot access the Network Admin panel. When I click on Network Manager, it gives a link like below.

https://https//www.maxray.com.tr/wp-admin/network/

Comment: I think that URL is constructed from the network path in the wp_site (or similar) table. Can you connect to the database and check that looks correct?

Comment: Is there anyone who can help? Our problem continues

Comment: The link you get is correct for WordPress multisite administration. Do you mean it doesn't show anything (blank screen)? Or you don't know what to do there?

Comment: P.S. you probably want to [merge this account](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) with the one that created the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have an extra https// in your site configuration somewhere.

If you look in wp-config.php you should have

```php
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.maxray.com.tr' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
```

and in the database table wp_site you should have

| id | domain | path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `www.maxray.com.tr` | / |

In particular neither copy of your domain here should be `https://www.maxray.com.tr/` - no https:// and no trailing /, just `www.maxray.com.tr`.

---

If it's not that, then you probably have a bad filter somewhere (e.g. [network_site_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/network_site_url/)) that's trying to prefix your domain with https// (without the colon). I'd search your mu-plugins folder for that.